# Fatal error: Call to a member function create()

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I refered to https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-create-an-admin-form-look-like-a-configuration-page-magento-2-configuration-p3/ but there is an issue.

```
namespace Demo\Pro\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

class Configuration extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{


/**
    * @var PageFactory
    */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
 * constructor
 *@param Context $context
 *@param PageFactory $resultPageFactory;
 * @return void
 */
protected function _construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
     \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    parent::_construct($context);
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
}

/**
* Index action
*
*@return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
*/
public function execute()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $this->getRequest()->setParam('section','demo_pro');
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Demo_Pro::Configuration');
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('SL Pages Authentication'));
    return $resultPage;
}
}
```

Comment: This is the error - Fatal error: Call to a member function create() on null in \Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Configuration.php on line 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor to public and add one more underscore to your constructors name and it's parent too. May fix it.